# Python 2.7 Tkinter Label with Image "pyimage doesn't Exist"

Tags: image, python-2.7, tkinter, label

I googlet a lot and made some adaptions to my code which still didn't fix the problem.

My Code:

```
photo = PhotoImage(file="D:/AE theoretische Neuropsychologie/image.gif")
w = Label(app, image=photo)
w.photo = photo
w.pack()
```

Gives me the following Error (-tracebacks)

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> ```
>
> File "", line 1, in 
>     File "C:\Users\Asus\Anaconda2\lib\site->packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py",
>   line 699, in runfile
>       execfile(filename, namespace)   File "C:\Users\Asus\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py",
>   line 74, in execfile
>       exec(compile(scripttext, filename, 'exec'), glob, loc)   File "D:/AE theoretische
>   Neuropsychologie/PythonReps/vCGPDM/Segmentation/extremePointsMotion.py",
>   line 45, in 
>       w = Label(app, image=photo)   File "C:\Users\Asus\Anaconda2\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 2591, in
>   **init**
>       Widget.**init**(self, master, 'label', cnf, kw)   File "C:\Users\Asus\Anaconda2\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 2090, in
>   **init**
>       (widgetName, self._w) + extra + self._options(cnf))
>   **_tkinter.TclError: image "pyimage8" doesn't exist**

[Things I checked]

https://www.daniweb.com/programming/software-development/threads/154237/tkinter-problem
https://mail.python.org/pipermail/tutor/2002-May/014584.html

Comment: please show a _complete_ working program that illustrates this error. You are leaving out a lot of details such as how and when you create the root window, whether this code is in a function or not, etc. Please read http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Ok I dont know why, but somehow it now just works with app  = Tk()
So this thread could be closed

Answer (score -1):

Replacing
    app = Tk()
with
    app = Toplevel()

fixed, however created a new Problem: The code now produces 2 windows. One with both Buttons and one with the both labels
indentation not as I expect (of course everything after if is moved in)

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
app = Toplevel()
app.title("Extreme Points in Motion Segmentation of BVHs")
app.geometry('450x300+200+200')
btnSelectF = Button(text='Open BVH File',width='20', command=callback)
btnSelectF.pack()
label = Label(app,text="no File selected",height=4)
label.pack()
photo = PhotoImage(file="D:/AE theoretische Neuropsychologie/PythonReps/vCGPDM/Segmentation/image.gif")
w = Label(app, image=photo)
w.photo = photo
w.pack()
btnCompute = Button(text='Compute Segmentation',width='20', command=computeSegmentation)
btnCompute.pack()
btnCompute.config(state="disabled")
app.mainloop()
```

Also I found this reply on the Solution

> That's not really a proper fix because you rely on an imlicit root
>   window created when the first widget is created. You end up with a
>   variable root which isn't actually the true root window.